# How to show history with timestamp

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I made some execution of command on linux shell. But I forgot when I did.

I executed the command `history` , it shows me all the commands that I made.

Is it possible to see the timestamp of these commands?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

run the below command in terminal :

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "
```

Or, to make the change permanent for the current user:

```
echo 'export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
history
```

Comment: This is for bash only.

Answer (score 5):

As explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/391082/how-to-see-time-stamps-in-bash-history):

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d%m%y %T "
```

then type

```
history
```